# Submit button of a Google Sheet sidebar not working (2 updated)

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I'm trying to make a sidebar for inputting personal expenses but the submit button isn't working. Would appreciate it if anyone can take a look at the sheet and the AppScript. Feel free to make edits as you see fit. Thanks!

I've asked a similar question in the past but the code is different.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g8k_uYBUC9HkmYd9oDpCzcTp3fkY6qxaNpeQKVJPvQ4/edit#gid=1349359857

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

#### 1. There is no element called `displayReturn` in your HTML code.

This is why the button is not working and only showing an error in the console. Based on the [original source](https://codewithcurt.com/how-to-create-a-bootstrap-sidebar-form-on-google-sheets/), you could add this element at the end of the code.

[image]

```html
...
    <div class="block">

    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <strong>Footer</strong> Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="displayReturn"></div>
</body>
```

#### 2. There are multiple elements with the same `id`.

JavaScript will take the first element with the requested Id as it assumes that it is unique, using the current implementation it will pass the element coded before the one that you're trying to use, for example:

- Change from:

```html
      <div class="field" id="description">
        <label class="label">Description</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="description" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        </div>
      </div>
```

- to:

```
      <div class="field" for="description">
        <label class="label">Description</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="description" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        </div>
      </div>
```

### Working HTML body:

```html
<body>

  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="tablinks is-active">
        <a onclick="openTab(event, 'Home')">
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container is-fluid">

    <div class="tabcontent" id="Home">
      <div class="field" for="date">
        <label class="label">Date</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="date" type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="description">
        <label class="label">Description</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="description" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="remarks">
        <label class="label">Remarks (optional)</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="remarks" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="payment_method">
        <label class="label">Payment method</label>
        <div class="control">
          <div class="select is-rounded">
            <select id="payment_method">
            <option></option>
        <? var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("G12:G51").getValues().flat().filter(String); ?>
    <? values.forEach(function(value) { ?>
      <option value="<?= value ?>"><?= value ?></option>
    <? }); ?>
      </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="amount">
        <label class="label">Amount</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input is-rounded" id="amount" type="number" step="0.01">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="category">
        <label class="label">Category</label>
        <div class="control">
          <div class="select is-rounded">
            <select id="category">
        <option></option>
        <? var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("C12:C51").getValues().flat().filter(String); ?>
    <? values.forEach(function(value) { ?>
      <option value="<?= value ?>"><?= value ?></option>
    <? }); ?>
      </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field" for="subcategory">
        <label class="label">Sub-category</label>
        <div class="control">
          <div class="select is-rounded">
            <select id="subcategory">
        <option></option>
        <? var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("D12:D51").getValues().flat().filter(String); ?>
    <? values.forEach(function(value) { ?>
      <option value="<?= value ?>"><?= value ?></option>
    <? }); ?>
      </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field is-grouped">
        <div class="control">
          <button class="button is-link is-rounded" onclick="SubmitRecord()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <button class="button is-link is-light is-rounded">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">

    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <strong>Footer</strong> Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="displayReturn"></div>
</body>
```

---

Reference:

- [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)